# React setting innerHTML over and over, causing scripts to be loaded many times

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux, react-router, single-page-application

So, I have a React universal project I am setting up. There is a Login modal which sits at the highest level of the app, because it needs to be able to be opened on any page.

Inside this Login modal I have some stuff, including a FacebookLogin, GoogleLogin, and some FontAwesome icons:

```
<Row>
  <Col>
    <FacebookLogin
      appId='123456789'
      autoLoad
      callback={this.handleFacebookLogin}
      fields='name,email,birthday'
      textButton='Login with Facebook'
      icon='fa-facebook-square'
    />
  </Col>
</Row>

<Row>
  <Col>
    <GoogleLogin
      callback={this.handleGoogleLogin}
      clientId='123456789'
    >
      <FontAwesome name='google'/> Login with Google
    </GoogleLogin>
  </Col>
</Row>
```

On initial page load, the Facebook api, Google api, and FontAwesome are *not* loaded. When I open the modal for the first time and the component mounts (presumably), the three scripts are loaded. Okay, good.

But, if I close the modal and reopen it, the scripts are loaded *again*. In the network tab, the "Initiator" of these script tags being written into the DOM is `setInnerHTML.js:30`, which is this bit of the React source code:

```
var setInnerHTML = function (node, html) {
  node.innerHTML = html;
};
```

What is going on here? The project is based off [this boilerplate](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example) and I have changed very little, so I have no idea why this sort of poor behaviour is happening.

Comment: I can't find the `*Login` components in that boilerplate, so I assume that you implemented them yourself? If so, can you show one of them? You should be aware that the modal will probably render its children each time it's shown, so if those children load external scripts (on `componentDidMount` or something), that will also happen each time the modal is shown.

Answer (score 0):

well from what I understand, it looks like the code that loads the scripts is being injected to the dom whenever the modal is being opened, therefore that is the expected output. If you don't want that you have to modify those components yourself to do a check if the scripts already exist in the dom before injecting it.